# XAML binding to an immutable struct

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8

I have some [DownloadOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.downloadoperation)s in my Windows 8 app. The DownloadOperation has a property `Progress` which contains `Status`, `TotalBytesToReceive`and `BytesReceived`. I tried to data-bind to those  in my XAML markup, but i got [some errors](http://pastebin.com/Uus5VTpJ). I then found out that it's impossible to bind to a struct, which [BackgroundDownlodProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloadprogress) is.
The only solutions I found online were to make the struct mutable which is impossible for me because it's not my code.

I tried to wrap the DownloadOperation into a Wrapper class that has class properties for DownloadOperation.Progress.Status, DownloadOperation.Progress.BytesReceived and  DownloadOperation.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive.

I would have to notify the system of property changes in ord to update the value in the UI though, and normally this is done in the properties' setter method. I have no setter though, because the underlying struct is read-only.

How can I create a XAML binding to an immutable struct defined by the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DownloadOperation has a method called "`AttachAsync`", which returns an object of type "`IAsyncOperationWithProgress<DownloadOperation, DownloadOperation>`". You can use this return value to add a method that handles progress events. Every time this progress method is called you can notify your UI that the progress properties have changed. It should look like this:

```
var operationWithProgress = download.AttachAsync();
operationWithProgress.Progress = (asyncInfo, progressInfo) => {
    //send notify property changed events
}
```

Disclaimer: I didn't try to run a program using this solution, I was just searching the docs. Please comment if you have any problems with this solution.